# Azure Web App First time loading is slow

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Wep app runs in Azure and "Always On" is set to "On" but still first time loading (e.g. first time in a day.) takes over a minute to load a web page.

Can you give a suggestion how to remove this waiting time, because it is not acceptable to wait for such a long time for the web page to open?

Comment: First things first, do you actually know where the time is going? Have you looked at the network data in your browser's inspector for example? This could be client side (e.g. cached data expires and needs to be downloaded again), so rule that out first.

Comment: If you try to access the web page after somebody already loaded the web page it is loaded fast.

Alice tries to load the page - takes over the minute
After that Bob tries to load the page from another PC - takes some seconds

Comment: Your app, loading the first time, is simply going to take time to load. We know zero about your app, so there's no way to diagnose bottlenecks or suggest what to fix (aside from having you increase the performance tier). As far as being acceptable/not acceptable for wait time, you're talking about an edge case: The very first time. Seems like your end-users will rarely run into this.

Comment: It is kind of a web shop where you can buy a subscription for a year with a low number of clients, but because every user uses this only once it is important to get every user. The behaviour is similar to IIS starting again, but as I know Azure doesn't run IIS.

What are the possible bottlenecks?

Comment: "Azure doesn't run IIS" - no clue what this is supposed to mean. Azure Web Apps (web sites) uses IIS. Of course, you can use whatever you want in your own VMs, but you're using Web Apps so... you're using IIS.

Comment: @ShvedA - the bottlenecks will depend on your application.  What does it do first time it starts up...?  Does it load a heap of reference data from a sql database, does it need to connect to remote web services, what kind of app is it (mvc/web forms/...?) Is it pre-compiled?  Do you have any static initialising going on?  What service plan are you on?  what other dependencies do you have?  etc etc

Comment: Is this after an update or deploy of your app or does it happen after periods of inactivity?

Comment: It happens after a period of inactivity. It is an mvc application, containing only about 10 views. It has some initialisation, but with such a small app it shouldn't take long. In localhost with same database it loads for some seconds first time. It has remote web services but they are not used in initialization, but only when sending data. Don't quite understand what do you mean by pre-compiled. Service plan is: "Standard: 1 Small".

First time starting it just loads KeyValues (table contains less that 100 rows) from database and initializes the simple view with picture on background

Comment: since the issue (website performance issue) is a bit hard to reproduce on our side, could you please share the web app's info with us via leveraging the approach that pointed out at https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly?  I will dig into the your testing site and support you for further.